# how to pass multiple tables in dynamic sql of sql server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i can able to pass one table name as dynamically in dynamic sql. but i need to pass multiple tables in dyanamic sql and i need to include the table names what ever i am passsing same thing needs to be include as column name
Ex:

```
empno empname deptname tablename
101    krishna Research emp,dept
```

or

```
101    krishna research  emp-dept
```

to pass one table i am using the below code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE Dynamic_SP
      @Table_Name sysname
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;
      DECLARE @DynamicSQL nvarchar(4000)
      SET @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT * FROM  ' + @Table_Name
      EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
END
GO

EXEC Dynamic_SP 'EMP'
```

now i need to convert the below query into dynamic sql i.e

```
select empno,empname,deptname,emp-dept as tablename from emp inner join dept on emp.deptno=dept.deptno
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's a few interesting things here. What columns of these two tables do you want back? How do you want them joined? Here's a start: sys.columns contains the columns of tables, where sys.columns.object_id is the object_id of the table that the column belongs to. Join sys.columns to sys.tables on object_id to see what columns a table has.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to pass multiple table names, you can create a new type , say `create type SYSNAME_COLLECTION as table (table_name sysname);` and pass a table variable to your procedure. Then you iterate through each row and build your dynamic query.

However, having just `table_name` is not enough to generate correct query. `SYSNAME_COLLECTION` type should also have `clause` column(for instance, "FROM", "INNER JOIN", "LEFT JOIN", etc), list of columns to select (or formulas), maybe list of aliases. Since it's very dynamic, you may want to use `xml` type ; thus, definition of table type changes to something like

`create type SYSNAME_COLLECTION as table (table_name sysname, table_alias varchar(20) not null, clause varchar(20) not null, columns xml, order_num smallint,
primary key(table_name,table_alias) )`

Now you need to read each row in the body of procedure in the loop (and inner loop that reads xml column) , and build your query.  I'm pretty sure if you have enough time, it's possible to make it work; however, I doubt practicability of such approach . I'd rather consider not using dynamic sql or let application build the query...

Comment: Hi thank you for your response, i am not getting the concept whatever you explained could your apply the logic on my query?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is quite complex and it probably won’t work very well.  Your parameters are too wide and allow way too many special cases that will most probably break the code.

Unless this is some homework I’d strongly recommend you drop this approach and create standard stored procedures.

If you really want to create this then go ahead and read in more detail post a1ex07 wrote. Here are couple more articles to get you started.

[Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)

[SQL SERVER – 2008 – Introduction to Table-Valued Parameters with Example](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/)